# TypeError: BasePage.send_text() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'text'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, typeerror

I am working on Selenium Page Object Model, where I am facing this problem. I have made Base Page, like this:

```
class BasePage(object):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def find_element(self, *locator):
        return self.driver.find_element(*locator)

    def send_text(self, *locator, text):
        element = self.find_element(*locator)
        element.send_keys(text)
```

and I have created an Page Object for one of my page, like this:

```
class LandingPage(BasePage):
    USERNAME_EMAIL_FIELD = (By.ID, 'inputEmail')

    def __init__(self, driver):
          super().__init__(driver)

    def enter_user_name(self, username):
          self.send_text(self.USERNAME_EMAIL_FIELD, username)
```

While calling a method from BaseTest Page, like this:

```
home_page = LandingPage(web_driver)
home_page.login_user("userName", "userPassword")
```

I am getting following error:

```
TypeError: BasePage.send_text() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'text'
```

How is the any argument missing?

Answer (score 0):

Since you defined an args parameter `*locator`, every value you send to `send_text` will be in its `tuple`.

`locator` will be `(('id', 'inputEmail'), 'userName')` and `text` won't receive any value.

You need to send value to `text` parameter explicitly

```
self.send_text(self.USERNAME_EMAIL_FIELD, text=username)
```

Or you can just make `locator` a regular parameter, the value is already a `tuple`

```
def send_text(self, locator, text):
    element = self.find_element(locator)
```